npm when installing vuetify Report an error
I installed the option Nuxt Recommended (Everything from Default. Enables auto importing & layouts) according to the process of vuetify official website, but an Error was reported: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\xxxx\package.json'

No folders will be created at this time
I tried to install it with the npm init command, but I got Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\lingxing\web\nuxt.config.ts'
I really don't know what to do

Typically no errors occur for such a simple process, so any error you do run into should come with as much debugging information as possible.  State which command you used to create the project.  State every option you selected during the creation process.  Include any relevant logs.  Does the error occur during the creation process or when you run some other command afterwards?  When you look in the installation directory, what has been created?  I would not try to fix the project creation with additional commands like npm init.  Try deleting everything and trying again.
